# Why is rust-mongodb library slow compared to c++ version?

Tags: python, c++, mongodb, rust

I've  loaded this [airbnb dataset](http://data.insideairbnb.com/spain/catalonia/barcelona/2022-09-10/data/calendar.csv.gz) into a local mongodb(version 4.4.17) database called `sample_db` and collection called `barcelona_cal`. There are `6175334` records in the collection.

I created a small experiment to compare rust, c++ and python performances. The code for each langugage will simply get a cursor for the collection and iterate over it, increment a counter and note the time taken.

here's the python code:

```
import pymongo
from bson.raw_bson import RawBSONDocument

db = "sample_db"
collection = "barcelona_cal"


def get_docs(db, collection, document_class=RawBSONDocument):
    url = "mongodb://localhost:27017"
    client = pymongo.MongoClient(url, document_class=document_class)
    coll = client.get_database(db).get_collection(collection)

    count = 0
    for doc in coll.find({}):
        count += 1

    print('Doc count: ', count)


def main():
    get_docs(db, collection, dict)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

running this code using `time python3 test.py` returns the following times:

```
real    0m32.784s
user    0m28.076s
sys     0m1.888s
```

considering most of the time is spent in decoding the bson into python objects, I ran it again with the the default argument `document_class=RawBSONDocument`. It gave the following times:

```
real    0m12.132s
user    0m8.113s
sys     0m1.266s
```

Now, I repeated the same experiment with c++ with the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mongocxx/client.hpp>
#include <mongocxx/uri.hpp>
#include <mongocxx/instance.hpp>
#include <bsoncxx/types.hpp>


void mongo_connection_test(){
    mongocxx::instance instance{};
    mongocxx::client client{mongocxx::uri{}};
    mongocxx::database database = client["sample_db"];
    mongocxx::collection collection = database["barcelona_cal"];

    mongocxx::cursor cursor = collection.find({});

    bsoncxx::document::element el;
    uint32_t count = 0;

    for(auto doc: cursor) {
        count += 1;
    }
    std::cout << "Leads: " << count << std::endl;
}

int main(){
    mongo_connection_test();
}
```

This resulted in the following times:

```
real    0m3.347s
user    0m0.388s
sys     0m1.004s
```

Now, coming to the rust code. On rustc 1.65, with latest mongodb crate version 2.3.1, this is the equivalent code:

```
use std::io::Read;
use mongodb::{sync::Client, options::ClientOptions, bson::doc, bson::Document};


fn cursor_iterate()-> mongodb::error::Result<()>{
    // setup
    let mongo_url = "mongodb://localhost:27017";
    let db_name = "sample_db";
    let collection_name = "barcelona_cal";

    let client = Client::with_uri_str(mongo_url)?;
    let database = client.database(db_name);
    let collection = database.collection::<Document>(collection_name);
    let mut cursor = collection.find(None, None)?;

    let mut count = 0;
    for result in cursor {
        count += 1;
    }

    println!("Doc count:  {}", count);
    Ok(())
}


fn main() {
    cursor_iterate();
}
```

The code was built with `cargo build --release` and ran with `time cargo run --release`. I got the following times

```
real    0m18.727s
user    0m15.541s
sys     0m0.790s
```

I've run every version multiple times and got identical results. so all these numbers can be considered representative.

**Edit: I've run the rust binary separately like `time target/release/bbson` and that made very little, if no difference cos I did the build and run steps separately.**

So the question is why is the mongodb rust library so much slower than c++? One interesting thing that I noticed, which may explain this partly is that in the system monitor (ubuntu 22.04), the Network part shows that the tranfer rate is no higher than 64MB/s. Meanwhile for c++ it goes up to 600MB/s. I see similar thing when running the python with dict and that explains the slow bson decoding in python, so is the deserializer that slow in rust too?

[image]

Comment: debug / release / optimized builds ?  Did you reboot between test ? Did you run each test multiple times and if so could you do - reboot then report run 1, 2 and 3 for each test.

Comment: Don't use `time cargo run --release` that includes the build time and cargo overhead, use `cargo build --release; time target/release/crate_name` instead.

Comment: that made no difference to the times. I did the build and run steps separately. even timing the executable separately  as you mention gives the same timing. it's not that.

Comment: Then it doesn't include the build time but it still includes the cargo overhead of checking all the files **if** something should be rebuilt. But I agree that this is not where the extra time comes from.

Comment: I'm not sure who voted for closing, I think this is a well written question that deserves some attention.